# Mobile menu not working on Safari

Tags: html, css, wordpress, safari

We are developing [this website](http://welcomeocb.msf.be/msfmentor/) in Wordpress and I have discovered that the dropdown menu on mobile phones using Safari does not work. After some research I think the problem resides in something related to this CSS code:

```
.site {
word-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
-o-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
overflow: hidden;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
min-height: 100vh;
}
```

If I go on the safari inspector and deactivate `display: flex;` the menu appears. However if I comment this out and I upload the new style.css file, it doesn't work.

Any idea how can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If commenting it out doesn't work, as you sure that it isn't being overridden with another CSS rule somewhere else that you would also need to change?

Comment: I don't know. All I know is that I can't get it to work unless I deactivate that within the Safari inspector. In fact, why does it work if deactivate it on the inspector?

Comment: Did you check if that was the rule that you were actually deactivating, and it wasn't another that was overriding this? Without seeing it in action, there's no way that we can tell whats going on, so you'll need to debug it a bit more yourself if thats not the issue, and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to narrow it down.

Comment: To be honest I have tried several things to a debug it. The code I have put into the question is on line 5946 of the file in `wp-content/themes/longriver/style.css` I also have contacted at the same time Template Monsters as the template is this one https://www.templatemonster.com/wordpress-themes/63613.html If they reply I will post the answer here, but I was hoping someone could help. As for the minimal example, I am not skilled enough to reproduce it in a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example... Sorry.

Comment: To create a minimal example, you just need to either strip away everything until you only have the code that creates the problem, or start again with a basic html page and add the CSS back bit by bit until the problem starts. Its something that you should do for your own benefit - its one of the most basic debugging techniques that will help you track down most issues you have.